# parsing file using sed

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file that has some data I want to get automatically using a script

the file looks like this

```
var1 = value1
var2   =  value2
```

I am trying using `sed`

```
sed -n -e 's/^.*var2\(.*\)/\1/p'
```

but I cannot manage to remove the spaces and the `=` sign

In general I do not know how many spaces there are

the expected result would be:
`value2`

instead I get
   `=  value2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat file | tr -d ' ' | cut -d'=' -f2
```

Comment: This will remove spaces inside `value2` and show lines that don't match `var2`.

Comment: He didn't say he wanted to keep any spaces; he only said he didn't know how to remove them.  If he had said he wanted to keep spaces in value2, I would have given a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this:

```
sed -n -e 's/^.*var2 [[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\(.*\)/\1/p' testfile.txt
```

works

Comment: Shorter are `sed -n -e 's/^.*var2 [[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*//p' testfile.txt` and `sed -n  -e '/^var2/ s/.*=[[:space:]]*//p testfile.txt`.